# Strange Crash Behaviour - Late 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

My late 2016 15" MacBook Pro exhibits a weird crash behavior. It seems to crash at random times roughly every 20 hours of usage. It does so by becoming unresponsive. In particular, usually, the application I am currently using will fail to respond first. When I then try to quit or even force quit the application this Mac OS X function (I'm using Big Sur) will fail too. After that, I can still "click the buttons" of the graphical interface of Mac OS X, but there won't be any response from the system (shutting down the laptop does not work either).

So far the only solution has been to kill and restart the laptop. This started roughly 3 months ago (and it feels like it's getting worse - though that assessment may be influenced by my subjective judgement). Today I got a bluescreen for the first time (after the laptop stopped to respond, but before I killed it).

In response to the problem, I uninstalled all applications that were installed shortly before and after this behavior first occurred. Furthermore, I've always been using Avira so I don't think a virus is the culprit either.

How would you recommend I go about resolving this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is what the Memory Usage usually looks like: [image: Memory Usage - Running some code in the background]

Comment: My first guesses would be memory use - What does Activity Monitor show (say after 19 hours use)

Comment: @mmmmmm I added a screenshot of the typical memory usage. Note: the MacBook crashes regardless of whether I am running code in the background or not and regardless of whether I run via docker or without a container.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell if the Finder is crashing? By holding down mouse on the Finder icon on the Dock. It will show Relaunch Finder if it is crashing. If it is or not, the next thing I would do is boot into Recovery mode and run Disk Utility and repair the hard drive by using First Aid. Reboot normally. If this does fix the problem, you can boot into Recovery again and Install macOS. This will re-install the macOS. It will not affect data. It may reset the Dock settings and some System settings as well.

Comment: Thank you - I'll try that the next time it becomes unresponsive